# How nest.js handle a token on server side

Tags: session, cookies, next.js, token

Does Next.js provide any tool like php session to store token?

I have a API server and a Next.js app.

The app will call the API to get a token.

I have no idea how to handle the token on server side since I can't use cookies on server side and nextjs seems not providng any session like tool.

(The API is called by server side means I am not using useEffect to call the API. The axios.post() is written inside the export default async function Test(){})

Answer (score 0):

You can store the token in local storage/cookies by passing it to the main component. Then you can use cookie and middleware to have protected routes.